# Warning:Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_DIR assumed 'UPLOAD_DIR' Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php

```
 if (!is_dir(UPLOAD_DIR)) {
        mkdir(UPLOAD_DIR, 0777, true);
    }
```

Warning: Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_DIR - assumed 'UPLOAD_DIR' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

```
 if ($_FILES['file']['size'][$uploadedFileKey] <= UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                        $uploadedFileType = $_FILES['file']['type'][$uploadedFileKey];
                        $uploadedFileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$uploadedFileKey];
```

Warning: Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE - assumed 'UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

```
                      } else {
                        $errors[] = 'The size of the file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" must be of max. ' . (UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE / 1024) . ' KB';
                    }
```

Warning: Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE - assumed 'UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Warning: A non-numeric value encountere\

how can i fix this problem?

Comment: there is no predefined constants like `UPLOAD_DIR, UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE ` in php. incase you need to define that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Before you can use a constant, you must define it first. This must happen **before** any usage.

```
define ('UPLOAD_DIR', '/tmp/uploads/');
```

You can set the path to whatever you want, just try to make sure to use an absolute path.

Comment: You need to also define an **UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE** constant the same way you define **UPLOAD_DIR**.

Comment: Warning: A non-numeric value encountere\

Comment: You tried to divide an undefined constant by 1024. Fix the other things and that will go away.

Comment: i'm very don know why, error fixed but why my data don have save into my database study hard  coding hard :D hahaha